# Increase the font size of text

Tags: fontsize

When compiling the document, the pdf product looks like this:

[image: pictura]

The font size of the section is easy to change with `titlesec` package, but what about the remaining text?

I have tried with `\documentclass[size]{extreport}` but it doesn't works. When trying with size=12pt, 15pt there is no effect and with 20pt suddenly font becomes too big.

Here is an **MWE**

```
    \documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{612pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\LARGE\textbf{CURRÍCULUM VITAE}
\end{center}
\section*{\textbf{Datos personales}}
%{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
Nombre completo: the name

Fecha de nacimiento: 22\slash01\slash1994.

Edad: 24 años.  

DNI: 0..0.0 

Residencia: the residence

Celular: phone number

Tel: telteltel

Correo electrónico: 

Estado Civil: Soltero.

Nacionalidad: Argentino.

\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\large` ??

Comment: add large every time? that's not desirable I think..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: what do you mean by every time? you could just use it once, after `\begin{document}`  but what is wrong with the normal `\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}` ?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? This seems trivial.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle add large at the preamble didn't produce changes and I supposed you meant to use \begin{large}..every time I need to increase font size on the text

Comment: @Bananguin it imay be trivial, the problem is that what I tried doesn't work, I don't know why..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle extreport in 12 pt is too small I think..

Comment: `\large` (like all size changes) acts from that point for the rest of the document, if you want all the text the same size you only need to issue the command  once (not in the preamble) you say 12pt is too small, then use something bigger, the default is 10pt. Only you know what size you want!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the help. I don't know why with 12pt, 15pt.., font size doesnt change, but then, when I write 20pt it changes to a very big font size.. using \large worked quite good..

Comment: Did you try with `14pt` or `17pt`?

Comment: Is there any problem with 15 and 16 pt? 14pt worked! Thanks @touhami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The extsizes classes (extarticle, extreport, extbook, extletter, and
>   extproc) provide support for sizes eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve,
>   fourteen, seventeen and twenty points.

So one can use

```
\documentclass[size]{extreport}
```

where `size` is `8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt` or `20pt`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `[12pt]` option to the document class, like this:

`\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}`

Comment: Thanks, but I have written that it didn't work..

Comment: @santimirandarp what do you mean by "does not work" by default you get 10pt text and that option will give larger 12pt text. Your question is completely unclear, you do not say what problem you have just that "it does not work" and the image you show is not generated by the code  that you show.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't produce effect in the document, that's what I wrote in the post. I am sorry for the MWE, it have corrected it..@DavidCarlisle